# can't build F# project on Mac OS X

Tags: f#, mono

I used the yeoman fsharp template to create a Fsharp Console project and added

```
 <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="$(BuildDependsOn)" Outputs="$(TargetPath)"/>
```

to the project file.

The build using xbuild succeeds but no exe is created.

Output from xbuild:

```
Finished Target: Clean
Starting Target: Build (==> Clean)
Building project: /Users/roger/Documents/MyTest/MyTest.fsproj
......
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Build Time Report
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Target     Duration
------     --------
Clean      00:00:00.0044740
Build      00:00:00.3824361
Total:     00:00:00.4361535
Status:    Ok
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Adding a target named `Build` supersedes the one provided by FSharp.targets, so this is expected: you create a target and specify what its inputs and outputs are, but you don't make it do anything. What is the purpose of your custom target?